# Datatable Dynamic Drill down with Django

Tags: jquery, django, datatables, datatables-1.10

I want to have a tables where if you click on a row , it will allow user to drill down and get more info about that row. The number of drill down tables or details table should be dynamic. One row can drill down and show 3 records and other row could drill down and show 2 records.. I found this example http://jsfiddle.net/headwinds/zz3cH/ but I find it very complicated.Just wanted to know if there is any official solution to implement this?

```
[ { 'site': "USA", 'site_allocated': 4158L, 'site_used': 3581L, 'data': {     u'tenant1': { 'flavor_info': [ { 'flavor_allocated': 5L, 'name': u'abcdef', 'flavor_used': 4L }, { 'flavor_allocated': 5L, 'name': u'pqrst', 'flavor_used': 1L } ], 'tenant_used': 5L, 'tenant_allocated': 10L }, u'tenant2': { 'flavor_info': [ { 'flavor_allocated': 50L, 'name': u'aabbhdg', 'flavor_used': 50L } ], 'tenant_used': 50L, 'tenant_allocated': 50L }, }, }, { 'site': "FRA", 'site_allocated': 4158L, 'site_used': 3581L, 'data': { u'tenant1': { 'flavor_info': [ { 'flavor_allocated': 5L, 'name': u'hdjfur', 'flavor_used': 4L }, { 'flavor_allocated': 5L, 'name': u'kkdjf', 'flavor_used': 1L } ], 'tenant_used': 5L, 'tenant_allocated': 10L }, u'tenant2': { 'flavor_info': [ { 'flavor_allocated': 50L, 'name': u'hhdyfht', 'flavor_used': 50L } ], 'tenant_used': 50L, 'tenant_allocated': 50L }, }, } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

[DataTable Row Details](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html) It looks like you would create a template of the row(s) you want to expand, then that gets injected into the "parent" table. I'm guessing you'd have to write logic that creates another link allowing the user to expand once again.

Comment: in my case , the child rows are not fixed. Some rows in the parent table can have 3 child rows (flavor_info in my data)  and some rows can have 1 child rows. I need to create those rows dynamically.